# Why can't I store multi line values into a JavaScript literal?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [a more graceful multi-line javascript string method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150859/a-more-graceful-multi-line-javascript-string-method)
>   [Multiline strings in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/multiline-strings-in-javascript)

```
window.lastSavedContents = "test

tester";
```

That's my JavaScript Code. I get a firebug error saying:

> unterminated string literal [Break On
>   This Error] window.lastSavedContents =
>   "test

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed; that's simply not valid syntax. Use "\n" to represent a newline:

```
window.lastSavedContents = "test\n\ntester";
```

Comment: Hey buddy! They apparently let *anybody* in. And there are no evil plans, either, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @epas: What's the problem? I don't see anything evil in his answer.

Comment: @Marcel, it is an inside joke.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to mark new line in a JavaScript value you have t put there a newline character by putting `\n`:

```
var test = "test\n\ntest";
```

You can also visually expose new lines by escaping ends of lines like this:

```
var test = "test\n\
\n\
test";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/grcLH/1/

Answer (score -2):

You can concatenate it, of course:

```
var stringTxt = "";

stringTxt += "test";
stringTxt += "tester";

window.lastSavedContents = stringTxt;
```

Comment: But I want to preserve the newline

Comment: It's 'better' to use an array and `join` it to a string.

Comment: produces `testtester` which is not what the op is after

Comment: Ah; I see. I'll leave my answer up as an example of not properly reading the question.