# What's the equivalent of "here printing" in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript heredoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376431/javascript-heredoc)

I am trying to figure out the equivalent of the "here printing" from Perl (<<) for Javascript, but I don't seem to find the answer.

Comment: There isn't one. Also, this is a dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376431/javascript-heredoc

Comment: An even older duplicate, with more detailed answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/multiline-strings-in-javascript , courtesy of Raisen's comment in accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a bit of a clumsy way of doing it in later JavaScript versions.  I snagged this from [a blog entry](http://mook.wordpress.com/2005/10/30/multi-line-strings-in-javascript/).

```
var string = (<r><![CDATA[

     The text string goes here.  Since this is a XML CDATA section,
     stuff like <> work fine too, even if definitely invalid XML.

  ]]></r>).toString();
```

Comment: Awesome. That gave me some hints on what to look for and I found a working one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/multiline-strings-in-javascript
Thanks