# Add new line in javascript while displaying HTML

Tags: javascript, indentation

Is there a way to add new lines in javascript while printing html? So that the printed html is indented.

```
document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = "<div class="1"><div class="2">hello</div></div>"
```

Instead I want to something like this:

```
document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = "
<div class="1">
    <div class="2">
        hello
    </div>
</div>"
```

Comment: Sounds like you need something like heredoc.  Did you check out this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376431/javascript-heredoc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("id").innerHTML =
   ['<div class="1">',
    '    <div class="2">',
    '        hello',
    '    </div>',
    '</div>',
   ].join('\n');
```

Or just escape new lines:

```
document.getElementById("id").innerHTML =
"<div class="1"> \
    <div class="2"> \
        hello \
    </div> \
</div>";
```

Or the same with jQuery:

```
$("#id").html(
"<div class="1"> \
    <div class="2"> \
        hello \
    </div> \
</div>");
```

Comment: Second approach is nice. How to do the same in jquery?

Comment: @fhaider added an example with jQuery