# Quotes & escaping in Javascript

Tags: javascript, quotes

is there a smart way in js to insert mixedsingle and double quotes, like python

> """string"""

syntax? Or similar stuff, which I believe is present in Perl or PHP.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953682/javascript-here-doc-or-other-large-quoting-mechanism for some interesting workarounds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you're stuck with escaping the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Yea you have to use `" + string + "` or `"string"`