# Javascript Ajax call always return {"readyState":1} when read a file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i user the code:

```
 var test = $.getJSON( "about.json");
         console.log(JSON.stringify(test));
```

and i about.json is on same file directory but i only got **{"readyState":1}**
i don't know what is the issue.please help me if i am wrong.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706046/how-to-read-an-external-local-json-file-in-javascript

Comment: Two separate issues; one is local vs. remote resource, other is what the *A* in Ajax means.

Answer (score 5):

[`getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON) doesn't *return* what it gets, because it can't; the operation is asynchronous. Instead, it lets you provide a callback:

```
$.getJSON("about.json", function(test) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(test));
});
```

jQuery will call your function *later*, when the data has come back.

The reason you're seeing what you're seeing is that you're outputting a JSON string for the `jqXHR` object that `$.getJSON` returns. Apparently, the only enumerable, non-function, non-`undefined` property on that object is `readyState`, so that's all you see.

> and i about.json is on same file directory
>
> *(and from your comment below after changing to using the code above)*
>
> But at this time i could not get any data from json

Note that if you're doing this in an HTML file you've opened locally (e.g., a `file:` URL, not an `http:` or `https:` URL), some browsers (such as Chrome) disallow all ajax calls. When doing web development, it's important to use a server (even if it's `localhost`), because a lot of things either don't work or work differently when you're using local files.

Comment: i use your code But at this time i could not get any data from json.

Comment: @niteshsingh: Then there's *another* problem. You'll need to use the tools built into your browser to find out what it is. Use Ctrl+Shift+I (that's an "eye") or F12 (depends on the browser and OS) or look through the menus. Look in the "web console" for errors, etc.

Comment: @niteshsingh: I've added a note to the end of the answer, though, which may be what's going on now you've corrected the async thing.

Comment: In console i am not get any  error ,but i will check  for localhost issue  .