# How can we Read a local Json file in a html page without any server

Tags: html, angularjs, json

I want to read a local Json file from a html page. But I am not able to read the local Json file in HTML page that work for chrome and IE.
Is there is any way to do it without using any web server.

Comment: See this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706046/how-to-read-an-external-local-json-file-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have,
index.html & sample.json in the same folder,
you can do this,

```
$http.get('sample.json').then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
 });
```

of course you will need to run this from a controller, stand alone or in a directive, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution on the web, i didn't try it but according to the comments it should work

```
function loadJSON(callback) {   

    var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    xobj.open('GET', 'my_data.json', true); // Replace 'my_data' with the path to your file
    xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
            // Required use of an anonymous callback as .open will NOT return a value but simply returns undefined in asynchronous mode
            callback(xobj.responseText);
          }
    };
    xobj.send(null);  
 }

The function above will create a new instance of a XMLHttpRequest and load asynchronously the contents of my_data.json. I have gone with asynchronous but you can change the argument to false if you want a synchronous load. Thankfully all modern browsers support the native JSON.parse method. Remember our anonymous callback? here's how you use it.

function init() {
 loadJSON(function(response) {
  // Parse JSON string into object
    var actual_JSON = JSON.parse(response);
 });
}``
```

http://codepen.io/KryptoniteDove/post/load-json-file-locally-using-pure-javascript

Answer (score -1):

Create a JSON file named sample.json in a translation folder .Then in controllers use the below code to get the values present in JSON file

```
$http.get('translation/sample.json').success(function(response){
      console.log(response);           
});
```

or

```
$.getJSON('translation/sample.json', function(data){
    console.log(data); 
});
```

Comment: You can edit your question please, explanations are for the community, not for me ;)