# Read a JSON file line based on what it starts with using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, html

For example, I have a **JSON file called Stores.json** that has lots of numbers like 1142,1234,1890, etc and each one has an address associated with it. It looks something like this but there are **thousands of objects**:

```
    {
      "1142": {
        "Name": "P. Sherman",
        "Address": "42 Wallaby Way, Sydney",
      }
    }
```

I have already looked at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24378510
But I am still confused about how to read a file based on a string, such as "1142", because I don't know what line the number is on if there are many lines.

I tried:

```
var mydata = JSON.parse(data**[this is Stores.json]**);
addr = mydata["1142"];
```

Maybe I am just confusing JavaScript with PHP?
PHP code would work but I would like the JavaScript version.

EDIT: Assume that there are many objects in the file, I need to be able to select an object using a number. Basically none of the JSON is written in the Javascript Code.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Is `data` a string or already an object?

Comment: Please show us an example of the entire object (don't need fillers, but need to know all enclosing tags)

Comment: @BrunoLM Assume data points to a file.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst that is what the complete object looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON.parse takes a string

```
var data = "{\"1142\":{\"Name\":\"P. Sherman\",\"Address\":\"42 Wallaby Way, Sydney\"}}";
var mydata = JSON.parse(data);
console.dir(mydata["1142"]);
```

If your data is already in object notation, don't parse it.

```
var data = {
  "1142": {
    "Name": "P. Sherman",
    "Address": "42 Wallaby Way, Sydney"
  }
};
console.dir(data["1142"]);
```

Comment: Thanks, but that Object is one of many in the file, is there a way to load it from the file, without knowing what the file has in it? (basically none of the JSON is in the code.)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function getJsonObj(path, func)
{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open('GET', path, true);
    xhr.onload = function()
    {
        var jso = JSON.parse(this.response);
        var key = Object.keys(jso)[0];
        var obj = jso[key];

        func(key,obj);
    }

    xhr.send(null);
}

getJsonObj('path/to/file.json', function(key, obj)
{
    // do stuff
});
```

Using the above, you do not need to know what the "number" is as it assumes that it's the first object in the response JSON.

The function accepts a "call-back" function as second argument, so it's asynchronous (non-blocking); which returns the "number" (key) and the number's data (obj).

This will take care of "white-space" also, where if you read it line-by-line, your "number" may be on a different line when dealing with another json-data-output api in the future.

---

#### Edit:

If the above code does not work exactly as it is, try replacing the `xhr.onload` part with this:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if ((xhr.readyState == 4) && (xhr.status == 200))
    {
        // the rest here
    }
}
```

---

### Update

If you don't know what exactly is in the file, and need to filter out only the JSON part, then you can do something like this:

```
// ...
var txt = this.responseText;
var jso = JSON.parse(txt.substr(txt.indexOf('{'), txt.lastIndexOf('}')));
// ...
```

Then, if the parsed JSON is an array (or list of objects), you can iterate through them with something like this:

```
jso.forEach
(
    function(item, indx)
    {
        if (!(typeof item == 'object'))
        { return; }

        var key = Object.keys(item)[0]; // your object "number"
        var obj = item[key];            // your object number's value

        if (isNaN(key * 1))  // checks if the key is a number
        { return; }

        // continue here ...
    }
);
```

Use the code alterations above as you see fit in the right places accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, but that Object is one of many in the file, is there a way to load it from the file, without knowing what the file has in it? (basically none of the JSON is in the code.)

Comment: If the file contains only JSON, and those objects are a list (array) of objects, then you can just use it accordingly, as a list of objects. I'm not sure what you want to accomplish here, but if I know more I can edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: You may need to format the JSON source (text from file) before parsing it, I don't know, which-ever it is; the more you elaborate on the problem and the desired outcome, -the better answers you will get related to your specific needs.

Comment: Edited acordingly.

Comment: @AndreyNazarchuk :: i've added a check for numbered keys only. Remember to choose any answer that suits your needs, even if you have to write an answer yourself ;)

Comment: how would I find just the store number I am looking for? basically I need this code to find an address for a certain store number from a json file 1000s of lines long.

Comment: @AndreyNazarchuk :: I'm writing a new answer which will contain the edits and updates with "search" functionality as needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = {
  "1142": {
    "Name" : "Sample Name",
    "Address" : "My address",
  }
};
```

Firstly, the variable data has already been parsed, therefore

*var mydata = JSON.parse(data);*

is not needed. You can access the variables in this form:

```
var x = data['1142'];
alert(x.Name);
alert(x.Address);
```

Comment: Thanks, but that Object is one of many in the file, is there a way to load it from the file, without knowing what the file has in it? (basically none of the JSON is in the code.)

Comment: $.each(result, function (key, object) {
    console.log("Name:", object.Name, "Address:", object.Address);});

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, here is a more appropriate answer to your specific needs:

```
function findStore(numb, file, func)
{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open('GET', path, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if ((xhr.readyState == 4) && (xhr.status == 200))
        {
            var txt, jso;

            txt = this.responseText;
            jso = JSON.parse(txt.substr(txt.indexOf('{'), txt.lastIndexOf('}')));

            jso.forEach
            (
                function(item, indx)
                {
                    if (!(typeof item == 'object'))
                    { return; }

                    var key = Object.keys(item)[0];
                    var obj = item[key];

                    if ((key *1) == (numb *1))
                    { func(obj); }
                }
            );
        }
    }
    xhr.send(null);
}
```

You can use the function above like this:

```
findStore(1234, 'path/to/file', function(store)
{
    // console.log(store);
});
```

Comment: obj is the json object? so If I do `var addr = obj.address;` it will be the address?

Comment: @AndreyNazarchuk :: yes ;)

Comment: Only a pleasure. Remember to "up-vote" answers, questions and comments that are useful as it is appreciated and motivates others to answer your questions, or provide useful input.

Comment: haha i wish it would let me... Ill be sure to come back and do it as soon as i have 15 points

Comment: It has an error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input xhr.onreadystatechange (JSON.parse line)