# How to read and print data from json file using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have multiple json files with format like this:

```
{
    "title" : "abc",
    "desc" : "pqr",
    "img" : "mno",
     "isExpertApproved" : "true"
  }
```

I just want to add one button in my website where I can upload the file and without storing it anywhere I want to read the data of that file and I also want to store that data into database using javascript.

Is there any way for this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try out the [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader) object. It will save you having to upload the file

Comment: you can find you Answer here [How to read an external local JSON file in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706046/how-to-read-an-external-local-json-file-in-javascript)

Comment: What database-system do you use? You can't access server-based databases with only client-side javascript

Comment: I am using DynamoDB

Answer (score 1):

**index.html**

```
<div class='wrapper'>
    <p>JSON will be received in 3 seconds</p>
    <ul id='post'></ul>
</div>
```

**external.js**

```
new Request.JSON({
    url: '/echo/json/',
    data: {
        json: JSON.encode({
            text: 'some text',
            array: [1, 2, 'three'],
            object: {
                par1: 'another text',
                par2: [3, 2, 'one'],
                par3: {}
            }
        }),
        delay: 3
    },
    onSuccess: function(response) {
        show_response(response, $('post'));
    }
}).send();

show_response = function(obj, result) {
    $H(obj).each(function(v, k) {
        new Element('li', {
            text: k + ': ' + v
        }).inject(result);
    });
    result.highlight();
};
```

**css**

```
body {
    font-family: Helvetica, Sans, Arial;
}
p, ul {
    padding: 10px;
}
ul {
    margin: 5px;
    border: 2px dashed #999;
}
```

[Click here demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zalun/QsHw4/light/)