# JSON from separate file

Tags: javascript, json

How can I read a data from json separate file (f.e. 'data.json') in another file ('index.html') using javascript - in a simplest way ?

When I use it in the same file there is no problem:

```
data = '[{"name" : "Harry", "age" : "32"}]';            
var j = JSON.parse(data);            
document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = j[0].name;
```

But I cant manage to do that when I use external json file with:

```
'[{"name" : "Harry", "age" : "32"}]';
```

I'm looking for the SIMPLEST way (problably I'm missing some fundamental)

Comment: hey does this sound useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706046/how-to-read-an-external-local-json-file-in-javascript

Comment: Please try to keep your language appropriate and directly to the point of your question.

Comment: @Andrew - I'm using. I'm looking for a simple answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you use jQuery, you can do that with getJson function - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getJSON/

```
$.getJSON( "/someDir/test.json", function( data ) {
  console.log(data);
});
```