# SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I am trying to use a plugin called "Simplebar" found on GitHub, [GitHub SimpleBar](https://github.com/Grsmto/simplebar) but after downloading the scripts and looking at the simple.js script, it looks like it has an error

**"SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module"**

At the top of the simplebar.js file there are some import lines of code:

```
import scrollbarWidth from 'scrollbarwidth'
import debounce from 'lodash.debounce'

import './simplebar.css'
```

If I look in my browser debugger I see an error: "SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module".

Has anyone tried to us this plugin?

Comment: What framework are you using?

Answer (score 226):

I got this on Firefox (FF58). I fixed this with:

1. It is still experimental on Firefox (from v54): 
   You have to set to true the variable `dom.moduleScripts.enabled` in `about:config`

Source: [Import page on mozilla (See Browser compatibility)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

2. Add `type="module"` to your script tag where you import the js file

`<script type="module" src="appthatimports.js"></script>`

3. Import files have to be prefixed (`./`, `/`, `../` or `http://` before)

`import * from "./mylib.js"`

For more examples, this [blog post](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/) is good.

Comment: Tried both. Neither worked

Comment: The `type="module"` fixed this for me.

Comment: I am not sure if this is the right answer because if Firefox is involved, why the sample html is working fine and Firefox does not show the same error ("SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module") at that page ?

Comment: It worked for me. Double check (how) the imports/exports you're using. https://javascript.info/import-export

Comment: After being sure all these steps were applied I was still having this import/export error,  or even others (which I sadly haven't recorded anywhere, some of errors were `Uncaught ReferenceError : funcName not defined` or something ). Fixed when I **moved all functions/classes declarations on top-level**, *outside of any code block*. Hope this can help fix anyone with the same rookie mistake

Comment: Is firefox fixed yet? I'm still seeing it.

Comment: @chovy Experimental ES-Module support was added last week for workers in Firefox v111. The user still needs to explicitly activate the feature. See the following table: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker#browser_compatibility

Also, see this vite issue which has more info about it: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/8621

Comment: Moreover, functions imported from a js file with `type=module` are not recognized by the browser, I had to explicitly set it global in the `.js` using `window.function_to_use= function_to_use`