# JS : Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

I am learning firebase. I am using Kubuntu 21.04.
I installed nodejs and npm using :
`sudo apt install nodejs npm`
I created a project folder with index.html file `/home/username/project/index.html`.
I have also installed **firebase** using `npm install firebase` while I was on project folder in terminal.
I follow upto *STEP 2* as given in https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup.
My index.html content-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>User Auth</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>User Auth</h1>

<script>
  // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need

  import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
  import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";


  // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
  // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
  const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyC5zv8b1wfc0ykmpULeFI6tJa6Grk",
    authDomain: "user-auth-75223.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "user-auth-78563",
    storageBucket: "user-auth-78563.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "482788408547",
    appId: "1:482788408547:web:89e3ecdc24f3454576c00aa",
    measurementId: "G-VK5D45CCJ2"
  };

  // Initialize Firebase
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I run above html file in chrome. It is giving error in chrome's console.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Comment: `<script>` needs `type="module"` added to it.

Comment: If you are learning to build a web application with firebase, probably better to follow a guide such as below, so you can learn the related best practises as well.
https://developers.google.com/codelabs/building-a-web-app-with-angular-and-firebase#0
https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-firebase/

Comment: @evolutionxbox It is now giving 'indexing error' : **Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "firebase/app". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".**

Comment: Yup. If you're using modules directly in the browser you cannot use `npm` modules without using an absolute or relative reference. If you don't want that, use a bundler like webpack.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I have one folder named as node_modules inside my project folder. `/project/node_modules` .

Comment: That's correct, but the browser doesn't know that.

Comment: So Should I just need to import script of webpack and problem of indexing will solve ?

Comment: Read through the tutorials/getting started or webpack to see if it fits your needs. You can also use parcel, which doesn't need any configuration to run.

Comment: Okay thanks for your help. I am taking reference from https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/

Comment: @evolutionxbox My next question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69132670/how-do-i-add-more-fields-in-firebase-auth

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42237388/syntaxerror-import-declarations-may-only-appear-at-top-level-of-a-module#48583456 same error, answered her

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(node:9374) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63588714/node9374-warning-to-load-an-es-module-set-type-module)

Answer (score 3):

It's probably because you did not add
`"type":"module"` in package.json?

I fixed this issue by adding this line

source:
[(node:9374) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63588714/node9374-warning-to-load-an-es-module-set-type-module)

Comment: If the question is answered by another, please flag it as a duplicated.