# How do I add more fields in firebase-auth?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

After a long research on firebase-auth with email and password, I found that we can't give more than two fields (email and password).
In my assignment, they supposed to give three input fields (full name, email and password).
I have completed my assignment only with two input fileds (email and password) but they also want to store full-name in firebase.
My assignment is given bellow -
[image]

So, Is it possible to also store "full name" in firebase, If so then how ?
I could describe this question in another way, but I just tell you the truth.
**Please Help Me !**

Comment: Once you create an user or an user logs in, you can use their UID to store / retrieve additional data from another collection / table. So you have done part A; create the user with email and password. Now you can use the UID from the user to store the email in a ie userinfo table.

Comment: You mean I have to use database in firebase along with firebase-auth system which will store "UID" and "Full name" ?

Comment: _*from the user to store the email._ OR FULL-NAME ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase Auth object has a `displayName` property which you use to store user's name. However, if you are using Client SDK then you would have to create the user first and then update the name. This can be done in a single step if you use Admin SDK with Cloud functions or a server.

```
import { useAuth } from "firebase/auth"

const auth = getAuth();

const createNewUser = async () => {
  const { user } = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
  await updateProfile(user, { displayName: "Jane Q. User" })
  console.log('New user', user.uid)
}
```

If the *full name* consists of a first name and a last name, then you can add a `-` or any symbol between them e.g. `first-last` in `displayName`. Then you can read the name as shown below:

```js
const { displayName } = auth.currentUser
const [firstName, lastName] = displayName.split("-")
```

If you need to access the data from a server environment or any user management page, then it'll be best to store details of users in a database [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69132841/13130697) by [@TarikHuber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5519300/tarik-huber).

Answer (score 2):

You have basicaly two options for doing that:

1. as mentioned in the comments you could use the database to store additional data for each user `uid`
2. use [customClaims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) to store such additional data there

I would recommend the first one for more data if you need to store a lot of data and if you have less you could use the customClaims. They are limited in size so be carefull how much you save inside.

Comment: Thanks, Your solution is also good, but I am going to use @Dharmaraj solution.

Comment: I can agree with that :) I tought you need somethin beside `displayName`

Comment: Even I didn't know displayName property before his answer.