# retrieving a json file stored in local storage through ajax inside a webview

Tags: mobile, uwp

I have a UWP application that's targeted for mobile.  I have a local html and js file in the application along with some json files that the js file needs to call on.  The webview renders and loads the html file and js file correctly.

My problem is to be able to get the json file within the js file.  I tried doing an ajax call with the local path "ms-appx-web:///www//demo_data//demo.json".  The folder "www" is under the root project.  I get a 500 error from the ajax call with a textStatus of "Error".  What am i doing wrong and how do i get this to work?  There's not much documentation when i tried to google this or i might be googling the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried doing an ajax call with the local path "ms-appx-web:///www//demo_data//demo.json".

Firstly, the [ms-appx-web scheme](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj655406.aspx#ms_appx_web) may not be supported by [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Actually it is invoke the  `XMLHttpRequest`, the request need to be  `XMLHTTPRequest` standard. If you invoke the ajax call with `ms-appx-web` in a HTML directly you will get the error details:

> jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4 XMLHttpRequest cannot load ms-appx-web:///test.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

So secondly, the file should be in a web server. A local file may not be loaded by this method. And the uwp app is not a web server you may not use `jQuery.ajax()` to load the local file.

If you just want to show the json file inside the `WebView`, there're several ways you may reference.

1. Upload to a web server and use the `jQuery.ajax()`.
2. Load the Json file by uwp APIs and then load it by  [`NavigateToString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_WebView_NavigateToString_System_String_) method. For example(parse the json if needed):

   ```
   StorageFile f = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/www/test.json"));
   WebBrowser.NavigateToString(await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(f));
   ```
3. Hard code the content of json file directly inside the js as an object for dealing. For example:

   ```
   <script type='text/javascript'> 
       function doSomething() {
           var data = '[{"name" : "Ashwin", "age" : "20"},{"name" : "Abhinandan", "age" : "20"}]';
           var mydata = JSON.parse(data);             
           document.getElementById('myDiv').innerText ="name:"+ mydata[0].name;
           return "done";
       }
   </script> 
   //Invoke the script by webview
   private async void btninvoke_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       string result = await WebBrowser.InvokeScriptAsync("doSomething", null);
   }
   ```

More details please reference [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706046/how-to-read-an-external-local-json-file-in-javascript), and more details about the `WebView` please reference the [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/WebView).

Comment: The file can't be on a server.  It's an offline application.  That's why the json file is inside the local storage.  Is there any way to do this other than having the json somehow added during load?

Comment: @LazyProgrammer, so the other two ways are not suit for you? I'm not sure what during load you mean here, but may be you can try to load the json file like a common file and read the content from it. In uwp app we have StorageFIle relative APIs, in javascript you may try [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/javascript-read-local-text-file)