# HTML5 website - linking to large external menu file

Tags: html, external

I have a wordpress site but am in the process of building it as a html5 site (just to have it available, if need be). 
My question is about linking to a very large menu list that I would rather not have to copy and paste into ever page. I am hoping for something along the lines of...

link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="menu.css"

but linking to the menu list not the css. When I have tried this it doesn't work.
I have also tried this...didn't work

object data="html/stuff_to_include.html" 
    Your browser doesn’t support the object tag. 
/object

I would like to maintain the HTML-ness of the site but if I need a script does anyone know of a simple elegant solution?

Thanks
I would appreciates any suggestions, I am getting desperate.

Comment: I found a solution relative to my comprehension of PHP.  https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/how-to-call-a-menu-file-with-php/242421   I hope it works. I will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

The best way apart from keeping your menu in a database is to hold it in a JSON file. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706046/how-to-read-an-external-local-json-file-in-javascript) has a lot of info how you can maintain a JSON file and use it to populate info on your page.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. 
Does it make a difference that this menu list will be static (no updating needed) once its in place?

Comment: No, it doesn't make a difference. You can update a JSON file or you can leave it intact and use it to pull data from it.