# Download and importing json file to your firebase database

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been asked by a employer to download and import JSON file to your firebase database. I have used firebase in Android project. But in this case iI have applied for web development internship and I am not aware how to do the same for that is to have database i need to link an app for that. The employer has provided me with a script file and a JSON file. Am I expected to use a new app of my own?

Comment: Web apps work slightly different. I recommend looking at the [documentation for web developers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) and/or the [web codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/) to get started.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your script file will have details about the firebase project(API keys). You can import it as per [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup).

After that, you can import your JSON, something like this:

```
var database = firebase.database();
database.ref('path/where/you/want/to/import').set(yourjson);
```

To read json from your file, this answer may help you with that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24378510/1820644

To initially try, I recommend trying this on an new firebase project. After you got this working, try it out with the database you have been given. Create a new firebase project and try to do this thing on that project.

Hope it will help you.

**UPDATE:**

If you have a URL to your json file (and not the local json file), you might want to get it like this:

```
// using jquery
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ) {
            var database = firebase.database();
            database.ref('path/where/you/want/to/import').set(data);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: there is no such method `.set` in Firebase Admin, only `.setValue`