# Convert nested [Array] of {Object} to > {Object} | JSON File

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I am new to JSON data manipulation and I would like some help.

I have a JSON file that looks like the below:

```
[
  {
    "plannification": {
      "Data": 1,
      "DataType": "GB",
      "InclusionOption1": ".",
      "Default": false,
      "PropositionId": "GBT13456",
      "EssentialLink": "greatpdf.com/pdf.pdf",
      "Term": "1",
      "Segment": "part",
      "Id": "653284",
    }
  },
  {
    "plannification": {
      "Data": 1,
      "DataType": "FR",
      "inclusionOption1": ".",
      "default": false,
      "PropositionId": "FRT13456",
      "EssentialLink": "greatpdf.com/pdf2.pdf",
      "term": "1",
      "Segment": "pro",
      "Id": "984532",
    }
  }
]
```

I'd like to to convert this file to object and only pull data from `"Segment": “pro”,` as below:

```
    {
      984532:{
      Segment: "pro",
      EssentialLink: "greatpdf.com/pdf.pdf",
      PropositionId: "FRT13456",
     },
      etc.. {},
}
```

Where do I start?

Comment: any tried samples

Comment: your json is not valid. format it correctly the way you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter your array using `array#filter` on the `Segment` where the value is `pro`. You can use `array#reduce` and iterate through the array and using `Object#values()` take out the values of each object and create your new object.

```js
const data = [{ "plannification": { "Data": 1, "DataType": "GB", "InclusionOption1": ".", "Default": false, "PropositionId": "GBT13456", "EssentialLink": "greatpdf.com/pdf.pdf", "Term": "1", "Segment": "part", "Id": "653284" } }, { "plannification": { "Data": 1, "DataType":"FR", "inclusionOption1": ".", "default": false, "PropositionId": "FRT13456", "EssentialLink": "greatpdf.com/pdf2.pdf", "term": "1", "Segment": "pro", "Id": "984532", } } ],
      result = data.filter(o => {
        let { Segment } = Object.values(o)[0];
        return Segment === 'pro';
      }).reduce((r,o) => {
        let { Id, Segment, PropositionId, EssentialLink } = Object.values(o)[0];
        r[Id] = { Segment, PropositionId, EssentialLink };
        return r;
      },{})
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Great! thank you so much. This is exactly what I am looking for. Now I'll find how to pull from a file

Comment: Using Javascript, you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24378510/4758494)

Answer (score 0):

1 - Read the json file

2 - Iterate over the array of objects

3 - For every object, check your desired property

4 - If it matchs what you want, read the properties of the object and construct your object

Answer (score 0):

your data structure is not valid, at first correct the way you've written your json array of object so that i can figure out

Comment: This is unfortunately from an API, I cannot change the structure