# json file object modeling instead of mongoose

Tags: android, json, node.js, express, mongoose

I'm developing node.js application that should work both on a powerful server and on a weak android device.

In the server to access the database I'm going to use mongoose.

And what use for android? 
The android application must operate autonomously and database must be inside the device.

Is there a library similar to mongoose that stores objects in a simple json-file and performs the simplest operations to extract data from it?

Comment: For this problem you need fs module.And you should
[read this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706046/how-to-read-an-external-local-json-file-in-javascript)

Comment: Yes, but need not only to read data from a json-file, also need to implement many methods that are in mongoose, for example findById. Is not there already such a library?

Answer (score 0):

With fs module you can read,and write on json file.you want findbyid?

```
var a=[{id:1,topic:"you"},{id:2,topic:"im"},{id:1,topic:"you2"}];var z=[];var b=1;
```

`for (var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
if(b==a[i].id){z.push(a[i].topic)
}
}//now z =["you","you2"]`

Comment: Mongoose results are array

Comment: You can write all methods of mongoose,if you know arrays and arrays methods.

Comment: Mongos has many methods, not only findbyid. And use bust is not very productive. For example, in Delphi there is a superobject that uses hash to search in the json. It is a pity that there is no ready solution. Yes, I understand that I will write everything myself.

Comment: I cant join github now because we use filter.