# .log file read and convert to json

Tags: javascript, json

I have .log file and I need to get this file in javascript and convert to JSON. I try this

```
var j= readTextFile("log991/sensorData.log");
        console.log(j);
        var jsonnn = JSON.stringify(j);  
        console.log(jsonnn);
```

But I only get path in console log. Is there any way to make this?

this is how .log file looks

```
2018-04-03 15:47:58,873 INFO log(17) batteryCurrent=-0.45, solarCurrent=3.27, 
hybridCurrent=0, batteryVoltage=12.88, solarVoltage=13.09
2018-04-03 15:48:00,074 INFO log(17) batteryCurrent=-0.45, solarCurrent=3.27, 
hybridCurrent=0, batteryVoltage=12.88, solarVoltage=13.09
2018-04-03 15:48:01,274 INFO log(17) batteryCurrent=-0.4, solarCurrent=3.28, 
hybridCurrent=0, batteryVoltage=12.89, solarVoltage=13.1
```

thnx

Comment: what is `readTextFile`,guess an async operation

Comment: Could try `readTextFile.readSync`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read an external local JSON file in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706046/how-to-read-an-external-local-json-file-in-javascript)

Comment: JSON what ? file ? array ?

Comment: how does your `.log` file look like ? it should be parsable to json

Comment: @GeorgeBailey i edit my question with example of .log file. I need json file because i need to make simple chart from this

Comment: you want this file to be converted to json ? there is no valid json in this file

Comment: I have not yet decided which graph I will use, first I wanted to try to convert to json. Do you have any advice on how to convert it best so that you can use the data in the graph? This is only local to currently make some checks, it will not go into production and may also be some "workaround". Probably i will use it in google chart https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart

Comment: what keys/values you need to get from this log file to convert it into a valid json

Comment: Datetime, batteryCurrent, solarCurrent, hybridCurrent, batteryVoltage and solarVoltage.

Comment: @Arter have updated the code did it work in your system ??

Comment: @ashwintastic thnx, i will try your new solution tomorow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code *used synchronous version*

```
const fs = require('fs');
var text = fs.readFileSync('/somepath/a.txt','utf8')
console.log (text)
```

try this code to convert into json

```
const fs = require('fs');
var text = fs.readFileSync('/somepath/a.txt','utf8')
array = text.split("\n")
var dataArray = [];
for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
  if(array[i] == ''){continue}
  let tempArray = []
  tempArray = array[i].split(",");
  dataArray.push(tempArray)
};

json = {};
var c = 1;
dataArray.forEach( (e1) =>{
  isdate = true;
  var tempjson = {};
  e1.forEach( (e2) =>{
    var key;
    if(isdate )  {
        key = 'date';
        tempjson[key] = e2;
        isdate = false;
    }
    else if(e2.includes("batteryCurrent")){
        key = "batteryCurrent";
        tempjson[key]= e2.split("batteryCurrent=")[1]
    }
    else{
        var arr = e2.split("=");
        key  = arr[0].trim();
        tempjson[key] = arr[1];
    }
  })
  json[c] = tempjson;
  c++
});

console.log(json)
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you using node?

```
const fs = require('fs')

fs.readFile('log991/sensorData.log', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
  console.log(data)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `readFile` method of `fs` module.

```
var fs = require('fs')

fs.readFile('log991/sensorData.log', 'utf8', function(err, data) {

  console.log(data)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i fix this with python

```
import json 
a = open('log991/sensorData.log','r')
text = a.read()
text_as_list = text.split('\n')
keys = text_as_list[2].split()
result = []
for item in text.split('\n')[4:len(text_as_list)]:
temp_dict = {}  
for i,j in zip(keys,item.split()):  
    if j.isdigit():         
        temp_dict[i] = int(j)
    else:
        temp_dict[i] = j
result.append(temp_dict)
print (json.dumps(result))
```