# pm2 logging pm2.log to JSON

Tags: node.js, pm2

I searched but didn't find it, is it possible to change `pm2 logs` (specifically `pm2.log` file, not apps logs) to log in `JSON` format?

Yes, with apps logs its possible via ecosystem file, but about `pm2` itself?

Answer (score 0):

No, But you can log pm2 start into a .log format file

```
pm2 start server.js --output="/path/to/file.log" --error="/path/to/file.log"  
# or
pm2 start server.js --log="/path/to/file.log"
```

Be aware that writing output and error logs to the same file may increase your effort to search for error entries within the log file.

[More detailed information about pm2 log](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/pm2-log-handling)

[More detailed information about pm2 log [official site]](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/log-management/#:%7E:text=options%20on%20how-,CLI,-When%20running%20pm2)

[example convert .log file to json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49730175/log-file-read-and-convert-to-json/49730255)