# Get array data from js file using java script html

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Hello expert Please Help..

So I have 2 problem to get some array from raw file

First on html when try get array from js using getData function always return not define

Second Get array from txt file that only contain raw data no function at all

index.html

```
<script>
  var myData = []
  myData.push({id: 999,name: "Zee"}); //just for add some data
  //myData = getData(); << error not defined
  console.log(myData);
</script>
```

util.js

```
function getData() {
  array = [{id: 1,name: 'Alpha'}, 
           {id: 2,name: 'Beta'}]
  /*
  array = some file
  this file only contain this
  {id:1,name:'Alpha'},
  {id:2,name:'Beta'}
  */
  return array;
}
```

data.txt

```
 {id:1,name:'Alpha'},
 {id:2,name:'Beta'}
```

How to make this happen..

Comment: The function is defined _after_ it is being called. In the snippet, the HTML runs first, and then the JavaScript. You may try to enclose the function definition in the `script` tag itself.

Comment: the function is on other file.js

Comment: Okay, but the conclusion is still same. You cannot call a function prior to its definition. That's simply an invalid call.

Comment: I've add an answer @IkutoTohoin, check it out

Comment: I've edit my question to make it easier.. hope you understand now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your **html** file, link script file which includes `getData()` function.

```
<script src="filename.js"></script>
<script>
  var myData = getData();
  myData.push({id: 999,name: "Zee"});
  console.log(myData);
</script>
```

For second question, you may want to take a look at the following question. Answers are already there.

[How to read an external local JSON file in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706046/how-to-read-an-external-local-json-file-in-javascript)

Comment: ok thanks.. I got wrong on src="filename.js"
how about the 2nd question?

Comment: You would want to save the data in a `.json` file and get it with `fetch()`. (I'm not showing you how, just giving some clues xD)

Comment: If you're just starting to learn javascript, I'd say you avoid facing that problem for now (since it is a little complicated for beginners).

Comment: Thanks @Khay, but more I read id more confuse I am..
I wish I can make some like `array = readfile(data.txt)`
maybe you can help here
[Code](https://plnkr.co/edit/7mxyFd2ad9U2s8T4x82N?p=preview).

Comment: @mauroc8 yeah im just learn java and I want to learn the basic, avoid template or plugin stuff as possible
if can I don't want to change anything on data.txt moreover change the file type

Comment: @IkutoTohoin Java and JavaScript are two different languages.

Comment: I try learning .js one, why everyone make this so hard?
can you just complete [This Code](https://plnkr.co/edit/7mxyFd2ad9U2s8T4x82N?p=preview) change the `array = readfile(data.txt)` into something simple

Comment: No. There is no "simple" way of reading a file, because it has to be done asynchronously. I recommend you changing `data.txt` to `data.js`, and add it to the html: `<script src="data.js"></script>` right before your other script.

Comment: And you'd also have to change the contents of `data.js` to: `var data = [ {...}, {...}  ]`. Then you'd have `data` as a global variable.

Comment: @mauroc8 that data.txt is access from util.js not from html..
and consider that data.txt is read only.. no change at all
and khay already told me about using src on html so I can access function on util.js

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been solved at 24 August using code below

Util.js

```
function readTextFile(file) {
  var allText;
  var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
  rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
  rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (rawFile.readyState === 4) {
      if (rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0) {
        allText = rawFile.responseText;
      }
    }
  };
  rawFile.send(null);
  return allText;
}

function getData() {
  var str = "[" + readTextFile("data.txt") + "]";
  var array1 = [str];
  var array2 = JSON.parse(array1);
  return array2;
}
```

index.html

```
<script src="util.js">
  var myData = []
  myData = getData();
  console.log(myData);
</script>
```