# Expected a JSON object, array or literal.json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, error-handling, literals

I have a JSON file I use to store quotes for some Quote Generator I'm building.
Recently I got this error in my terminal (see screenshot below).

`Expected a JSON object, array or literal.json`

This is what my JSON looks like

```
data = [
{
    "number": "1",
    "author": "Von R. Glitschka",
    "quote": "The client may be king, but he's not the art director."
},
{
    "number": "2",
    "author": "Frank Capra",
    "quote": "A hunch is creativity trying to tell you something."
},
{
    "number": "3",
    "author": "Steven Heller",
    "quote": "As a profession, graphic designers have been shamefully remiss or ineffective about plying their craft for social or political betterment."
}]
```

I've tried all I could. but the error keeps coming, what could be wrong?

[image]

Comment: It'd help to see the stack trace and what led to the error. What action are you trying to perform that yields this error?

Comment: I'm trying to store quotes in JSON and serve to HTML.

Comment: Although it still works fine, quotes are served even with this error, but I still feel something is wrong?

Comment: This is a valid array, can you tell us how you are calling it? Show us the code that is using it?

Comment: How are you serving the quotes?

Comment: This is the JavaScript code that is using this JSON             
`console.log(data);
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);
document.getElementById('quote').innerHTML = data[random].quote;
document.getElementById('author').innerHTML = data[random].author;`

Comment: @SaraChipps `var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);`

Comment: Are you sure this has anything at all to do with json?

Comment: sigh.. you put javascript in a json file. remove the javascript and leave the json.

Comment: Yeah! Was about to ask that, is the data contained in `.js` file or `.json` file?

Comment: the quotes are in the json, I have a separate .js file

Comment: a JSON **file** should not contain `data = `

Answer (score 11):

You just need to format your file a bit like this:

```
{
  "data" : [
    {
        "number": "1",
        "author": "Von R. Glitschka",
        "quote": "The client may be king, but he's not the art director."
    },
    {
        "number": "2",
        "author": "Frank Capra",
        "quote": "A hunch is creativity trying to tell you something."
    },
    {
        "number": "3",
        "author": "Steven Heller",
        "quote": "As a profession, graphic designers have been shamefully remiss or ineffective about plying their craft for social or political betterment."
    }]
}
```

And save this with a `.json` extension.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but finally figured it out like this:
firstly, you need to make sure you have an `eslintrc.json` file, and then inside that json file you add this json object:

```
{
  "extends": [
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended"
  ]
}
```

which also works if you've a typescript or prettier errors.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurred for me but mine one just gone by changing file extension form json to js.

Answer (score -2):

It looks like, given the data you have and the code you are using to get a random number, your number is often exceeding the number of objects you have in your array.

For example,

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 50)
```

Could end up setting random to 13, which greatly exceeds the number of values in your array.

If you would like to get a random number between 0 and 2, you can use:

```
random = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(3));
```

Comment: How do I fix this?

Comment: I still get the error in my JSON. My js still works fine and the quotes render fine but the error still pops up in my JSON?

Comment: I see what is happening, the reason why you are getting an error is because you can't create variables in a JSON file. I would move that code over to your JS file.

Comment: I thought as much, someone gave that suggestion.

Comment: Is there no other method to do this with JSON without moving to JS and still get no error?

Comment: You could not set it as a variable and read the JSON file this way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706046/how-to-read-an-external-local-json-file-in-javascript

Answer (score -3):

An alternate approach to this is

```
data = [
{
"number": "1",
"author": "Von R. Glitschka",
"quote": "The client may be king, but he's not the art director."
},
{
"number": "2",
"author": "Frank Capra",
"quote": "A hunch is creativity trying to tell you something."
},
{
"number": "3",
"author": "Steven Heller",
"quote": "As a profession, graphic designers have been shamefully remiss or ineffective about plying their craft for social or political betterment."
}];

console.log(data);
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length); 
console.log(data[random].quote);
console.log(data[random].author);
```

Comment: Because the length of the array is dynamic it makes sense to use `data.length` as the limit for generating a random number so in the event it changes you are certain it'll never be out of range.

Comment: Actually, my code still works and I tried your's it worked too. But the error is pooping in my JSON and I don't know why?

Comment: Thanks for the `data.length` reminder. I was actually updating the data length manually but it makes more sense to make it dynamic as you rightly said.

Answer (score -4):

Well first, this isn't exactly a JSON format. This is an array of objects.
Your JSON can not have a variable assignment like the one you have 
     `var data = .....`
 Depending on why you are getting the error or what you intend to do with the data. You have 2 options:

1. Convert this array into an acceptable JSON object, like so:
   `$ JSON.stringify(data)`.
2. You can work with this data directly as an array that it is, just by storing it either as a js variable or in a js file. Then you can easily manipulate it like an array.