# How can I store data required to render React Components?

Tags: json, reactjs, web-deployment

I want to implement a game where players get clues to guess a pre-determined word. I have the clues and correct answers in a JSON file. Now, I want to create a user interface using React. However, I am unable to figure out how to make my data available to the React components. What would be a good way to do this?

I created a JSON file and included it as a script in html as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24378510/5959374), but I am still not able to accessible through the React components. I am a complete beginner at web development, so I would really appreciate it if you could explain the underlying concepts.

Comment: Did you read react docs? Did you try any tutorials beforehand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Create React App? If so, this should be as simple as placing the JSON file with the proper syntax in the src folder. Then you can use a simple default import statement using a relative path.

`import NameForImportedObject from './filename.json';`