# JSON and Icon Files not being read: "URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request."

Tags: javascript, json, file, import, fonts

I'm currently trying to parse my products.json file and an icon from FontAwesome. I was coding and then after coming back to my computer, both my JSON file and font-awesome files aren't being read, but I haven't touched my code.

Currently, my file system looks like this:

[image]
[image]

And below is my code which has the importing statements:

index.html

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Comfy House</title>
  <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">


  <!-- custom css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script defer src="/font-awesome/js/all.js"></script>
</head>
```

app.js

```
// responsible for getting the products from local storage
class Products{

async getProducts(){
    try {
        let result = await fetch("products.json");
        //let's wait until we get the result
        let data = await result.json();
        //have products variable hold array
        let products = data.items;
        //destructure the products
        products = products.map(item => {
            //get the title and price from the fields property
            const {title, price} = item.fields;
            //get the id from the sys property
            const {id} = item.sys;
            const image = item.fields.image.fields.file.url;
            //return the new product 
            return {title, price, id, image}
        })
        return products 

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
     }       
    }
}


class UI {
    displayProducts(products){
        let result = '';
        products.forEach(product => {
            result += `
            <article class="product">
                <div class='img-container'>
                    <img src=${product.image} alt="product" class='product-img'>
                    <button class='bag-btn' data-id='${product.id}'>
                        <i class='fas fa-shopping-cart'></i>
                        add to bag
                    </button> 
                </div>
                <h3>${product.title}</h3>
                <h4>$${product.price}/roll</h4>
            </article>   

             `
        });
        //insert the products into the productsDOM
        productsDOM.innerHTML = result; 
    }

...more code...
```

Comment: What do you do with the data being returned?

Comment: I'm parsing the JSON file to make a clean products array so it can be parsed in an HTML.

Comment: How are you running the website?

Comment: I'm running through localhost. The exact error is "URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read an external local JSON file in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706046/how-to-read-an-external-local-json-file-in-javascript)

Comment: Actually, I just found the error. If I run a live server from VScode, then it works. However, if I run directly from index.html, then it doesn't. How come this is the case?

Comment: The question I linked above answers that.