# How can i append a json value to an array outside the file

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to append all the values(without the keys) from this JSON file to an array in a javascript file

**JSON File:**

```
[
    {
        "href": "https://www.instagram.com/p/test1/"
    },
    {
        "href": "https://www.instagram.com/p/test2/"
    }
]
```

JavaScript file:

```
var ids = [];

const makePost = (id) => `
  <div class="post" id="${id}">
    <blockquote
      class="instagram-media"
      data-instgrm-permalink="https://www.instagram.com/p/${id}/?utm_source=ig_embed&amp;utm_campaign=loading"
      data-instgrm-version="13">
      Content - ${id}
    </blockquote>                
  </div>`;

let htmlContent = ''

ids.forEach(id => {
  htmlContent += makePost(id)
})

var d1 = document.getElementById('dynamic-content');
d1.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlContent);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could first use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get each href value, and the use [arra y destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to append the values

```js
  let dest = [];
  const array = [{
      "href": "https://www.instagram.com/p/test1/"
    },
    {
      "href": "https://www.instagram.com/p/test2/"
    }
  ]
  
  const values = array.map(entry => entry.href)
  
  dest = [...values]
  
  console.log(dest)
```

Comment: My JSON file is not inside the javascript file, they're two files('instagram.json' and 'script.js'), how could I do this in this situation?

Comment: You first need to get the content of `instagram.json` in your script, you could use fetch https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API or probably some of this ideas https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706046/how-to-read-an-external-local-json-file-in-javascript