# How to get data from JSON using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have put the data in JSON by using the setItem method:

```
localStorage.setItem('orderproduct', JSON.stringify([{imageSource: productImg, productTitle: title, productQuantity: qty, productPrice: finalprice}]));
```

and I check in the **inspect** is like this:

```
imageSource: "http://127.0.0.1:5500/allproductIMG/cake1.png"
productPrice: 490
productQuantity: "5"
productTitle: "Hazelnut Praline Cake"
```

Now I want to get the "productTitle" from JSON, I use this method:

```
let productdata = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('orderproduct'));
```

which 'orderproduct' is the variable I used to store the data. After that I use console.log to check the productTitle :

```
console.log("The product title is"+ productdata.productTitle);
```

But, the answer shows the 'productTitle' is undefined. Why? How can I get the "Hazelnut Praline Cake" instead of "undefined"

Comment: What does `localStorage.getItem` return?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava return the data that I have shown at the first

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read an external local JSON file in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706046/how-to-read-an-external-local-json-file-in-javascript)

Comment: @ArtiomB actually no, I am not using external JSON file, but I am using the getElementById to get the value and use setItem to store them into the local storage. For example: `localStorage.setItem('orderproduct', JSON.stringify([{imageSource: productImg, productTitle: title, productQuantity: qty, productPrice: finalprice}]));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must destruct the array before accessing the inner object,

```
console.log("The product title is"+ productdata[0].productTitle);
```

Otherwise you can save it without the array

```
localStorage.setItem('orderproduct', JSON.stringify({imageSource: productImg, productTitle: title, productQuantity: qty, productPrice: finalprice}))
```

Comment: This is the code I used to set the item:
`localStorage.setItem('orderproduct', JSON.stringify([{imageSource: productImg, productTitle: title, productQuantity: qty, productPrice: finalprice}]));` Isn't it not a JSON format?

Comment: Then the answer is you must destruct the array before accessing the inner object, updating the answer

Comment: how to destruct the array first?? Sorry, I am the new beginner for JSON, I don't know how to do it

Comment: is it updated? I am new in using stackoverflow, I am not sure whether it is updated or not

Comment: I feel this is a single object so during saving, array can be removed and save as an object like localStorage.setItem('orderproduct', JSON.stringify({imageSource: productImg, productTitle: title, productQuantity: qty, productPrice: finalprice})); Then you can use your original code.