# Create table from multiple JSON files

Tags: json, csv, export-to-csv

I have over 3000 JSON files. What would be the easiest way to merge certain values from these files in one CSV table?

By example, each json has `date_joined`, `country.name` and `expertise[]` as keys. How would I combine these in a CSV like so:

```
date_joined,country.name,expertises
2021-09-13T21:40:08.567023Z,USA,"X, Y, Z"
2021-09-15T21:21:08.567033Z,UK,"X, A"
```

Comment: Please share any approach & more informations about your tools used, like which programming language...?

Comment: Hi Maik, frankly, I care more about the output at this point. I was hoping it could be done with plain old JavaScript but it seems like a fairly painful resolution.

Comment: Is there any key in the JSON in order to check if a pair already exists? Like two JSON files can have users with the same id, but I guess you want to remove duplicates while merching, right?

Comment: There's an "id" and a "slug" both of which are unique. All files contain a single entry, though, which is unique in itself.

Comment: Please add also an example input

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: I'm not very much experienced with JavaScript, so please excuse me if I srewed up anywhere. Anyways I want to share my suggestion.

In the first step, I would build a function, which can read a JSON file from your harddisk. For that I am using the function by the user [@Stano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1422309/stano), which he suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34579496/16047487).

> ```js
> function readFile(file, callback) {    
>    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
>    rawFile.overrideMimeType("application/json");
>    rawFile.open("GET", file, true);    
>    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
>       if (rawFile.readyState === 4 && rawFile.status == "200") 
>       {
>          callback(rawFile.responseText);
>       }    
>    }    
>    rawFile.send(null); 
> }
> ```

You can now read a JSON file from your harddisk, like down below.

> ```js
> readFile("test.json", function(text) {
>    var data = JSON.parse(text);
>    console.log(data); 
> });
> ```

Let's take a look at an example by using the following JSON structure.

```
{
   "status": "Success",
   "data": {
      "key": [
         {
            "more_keys": "Some value"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

You can extract the values from the above JSON structure like this:

```
readFile("my_test_json.json", function(text){
    var data = JSON.parse(text);
    console.log(data.status); // => Success
    console.log(data.key[0].more_keys); // => Some value
});
```

With that being said you can now iterate through your files and merch the JSON files into a two-dimensional array. **Why?**. Because it's very easy to serialize a `.csv` file from it. For that I am using the following approach, which was suggested by the user [@Default](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1768690/default) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14966131/16047487).

> ```
> const rows = [    
>    ["name1", "city1", "some other info"],   
>    ["name2", "city2", "more info"] 
> ];
>
> let csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";
>
> rows.forEach(function(rowArray) {
>     let row = rowArray.join(",");
>     csvContent += row + "\r\n"; 
> });
> ```
>
> Then you can use JavaScript's `window.open` and `encodeURI` functions
> to download the CSV file like so:
>
> ```
> var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent); 
> window.open(encodedUri);
> ```

I hope that I could give you an idea how you can approach it, cheers!