# Freemarker insert String into Javascript code

Tags: freemarker

I would like to know how can I insert a string into a javascript code like in the example below:

```
     <script type="application/ld+json">
        {
          "@context": "http://schema.org",
          "@type": "Restaurant",
          "name": "Dave's Steak House",
          "address": {
            "@type": "PostalAddress",
            "streetAddress": "148 W 51st St",
            "addressLocality": "New York",
            "addressRegion": "NY",
            "postalCode": "10019",
            "addressCountry": "US"
          }
        }
        </script>
```

The problem is that when I try to insert the String between js it appears interpreted as HTML code with `%`, `&20` etc. I have tried with `?html`, `escape`, `no escape`, `?string`, `?js_string,` etc.

That's the String:

```
 {
          "@context": "http://schema.org",
          "@type": "Restaurant",
          "name": "Dave's Steak House",
          "address": {
            "@type": "PostalAddress",
            "streetAddress": "148 W 51st St",
            "addressLocality": "New York",
            "addressRegion": "NY",
            "postalCode": "10019",
            "addressCountry": "US"
          }
        }
```

And the code:

${myString}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert a large block of HTML in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16270761/how-to-insert-a-large-block-of-html-in-javascript)

Comment: You do it like `${myString}` usually... can you explain better what happens then? What do you mean it's interpreted as HTML code? What's `%` and `&20`?

Comment: For example whitespaces are interpreted as `&nbsp;` I mean that all is interpreted as ASCII code.