# JavaScript backtick multiline string not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have a large HTML string contained in a `var`. I'm using it to write to `innerHTML`.

The first example (with backtick syntax), which is the simplest, does not work in Internet Explorer 11.

Is there a way to get the first example to work in Internet Explorer 11 without having to use an array or newline characters?

### Does *not* work in Internet Explorer

Backtick `

https://jsfiddle.net/qLm02vks/

```
<div id="display"></div>

var message = `
  <p>this</p>
  <p>is</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>multiline</p>
  <p>string</p>
`;

// Write Message
var display = document.getElementById('display');
display.innerHTML = message;
```

### Works in Internet Explorer

Array Join

https://jsfiddle.net/3aytojjf/

```
var message =
   ['<p>this</p>',
    '<p>is</p>',
    '<p>a</p>',
    '<p>multiline</p>',
    '<p>string</p>'
   ].join('\n');
```

### Works in Internet Explorer

Single quote ' with linebreak \

https://jsfiddle.net/5qzLL4j5/

```
var message =
'<p>this</p> \
<p>is</p> \
<p>a</p> \
<p>multiline</p> \
<p>string</p>'
 ;
```

Comment: [No support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: you can use multi-line comments and `Function.toString()`...

Comment: see this answer with the idea to keep the HTML block in an invisible `<script>` container in HTML, then use its `innerHTML` at runtime in JS https://stackoverflow.com/a/16270807/961631

Answer (score 31, accepted):

#### Problem

The backtick syntax for a string is a [*Template Literal*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), which allows for interpolation of variables within a string and multiline strings. They are not supported by Internet Explorer 11 (see more here: [ECMAScript 6 compatibility table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/)).

#### Solution

1. You can use a transpiler, such as the ever-popular [Babel](http://babeljs.io/). This will convert the template literal into the ECMAScript 5 syntax that Internet Explorer 11 understands.
2. You *could* opt-out of supporting Internet Explorer 11, and stick with support for Edge and other browsers that have native ECMAScript 6 support, though this is usually not an option.

Answer (score 1):

It is not the most elegant solution, but I solved this myself by minifying my multiline template (Vue) string, and encompassing it within single quotes instead of back ticks. This can be automated as part of the build step, so your code still looks legible for development.

Also ensure that any inner strings (like classNames, etc.) are double quoted so you don't accidentally terminate the string, thereby causing template errors.