# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token in EXT JS

Tags: javascript, extjs

Hi I am retrieving some values from database in onReady function of JS it gives me error Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Below is my onReady function

```js
var clientId = getFieldValue('editForm:clientId');
               if (!clientId) {
                   if ('#{applicationObject.attributes['isProduction']}' == true || '#{applicationObject.attributes['isProduction']}'=='true') {
                       clientId = '#{applicationObject.attributes['productionClientId']}';
                   } else {
                       clientId = '#{applicationObject.attributes['nonProductionClientId']}';
                   }
               }

   Ext.getDom('editForm:clientId').value = clientId;
```

The expected value of clientId is

> 1:ACP:cSHnNw4v7MhdAGuQ1QF0PnuVOh1PFVBz0u2hlzx81uMR7GJMUBGe08XIKmb/SE7WvMpeprAPPSQw
> gQd+N+fOdA==

In Chrome debugger it shows as below

[image]

Comment: looks like there is a line break?

Comment: I guess the new line character in the string but can't avoid the string as it's encrypted password. Any idea about how to handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are inserting a multi-line string the easiest here (if you cannot modify that string or do not want to split it and then concatenate using `'line1' + 'line2'`) is to use so called [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) as they support multi-lines. Please also have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42493557/javascript-backtick-multiline-string-not-working-in-internet-explorer) as it's not supported everywhere.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have Control over the string as it is directly retrieved from a JSON object(applicationObject) and the JSON object is created at backend based on user information in database.

Comment: But have you tried to use backticks instead of single quotes in line `'#{applicationObject.attributes['productionClientId']}'`?

Comment: Thanks, It's work with backticks ☺️

Just for my knowledge 
What is difference in single qoute and backticks?

Comment: I included the link to description of [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) in my answer already - you can find all the interesting details there.